# How to patch multi document yaml file on condition using yq?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, yq

Having YAML document something like:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-scraping
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: allow-webhooks
```

I am trying to get something like

```yaml
---
apiVersion: **networking.k8s.io/v1beta1**
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-scraping
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: allow-webhooks
```

So basically get document, if document has `kind: NetworkPolicy` then patch `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1`.

Ideally one liner, ideally with yq v4, but other solutions will be helpful too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) on versions beyond 4, you could do a `select` and update `|=` operation on the required document

```sh
yq e 'select(.kind == "NetworkPolicy").apiVersion |= "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"' yaml
```

The above works fine on `yq version 4.6.0`. Use the `-i` flag to replace the file in-place.

Answer (score 0):

Given that other solutions will be helpful - an alternative solution would be using [kustomize](https://kustomize.io/):

1. Create the kustomization.yaml file:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- network-policy.yaml
patches:
  - target:
      kind: NetworkPolicy
      group: networking.k8s.io
      version: v1
    patch: |
      - op: replace
        path: /apiVersion
        value: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

2. Run

```sh
kustomize build | kubectl apply -f -
```

or

```sh
kubectl apply -k .
```